# Issue with starting a Django project on OS X Mavericks

Tags: python, django, bash

I did a fresh install of of python via home brew and changed my path in `.bashrc` to this: `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/:$PATH`

`which python` gives me `/usr/local/bin/python`

`which pip` gives me `/usr/local/bin/pip`

`which django-admin.py` gives me `/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py`

Now, when I go to start my project with `python django-admin.py startproject my_new_project`, I am given this error:

`/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'django-admin.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Why is it searching in that location for the `django-admin.py` file?

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: remove the python at the beginning of your command.  Python won't search your path for the file, if you just run `django-admin.py startproject my_new_project` things should work.

Comment: Thank you, this worked.  I am following this tutorial, http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/requirements.html#setting-up-the-pythonpath, so I'm not sure why they instructed me to use python in the beginning of my command.

Comment: Please, only use the [official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/#first-steps) which is reviewed and is up to date.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Okay, will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend using virtualenv http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/

There should be plenty of tutorials out there for MacOSx

Comment: I tend to create a new virtualenv for each of my projects, with a requirements.txt to store all the dependencies I have.